# google sheets query function error:array would overwrite data, can get query to insert new rows instead of filling the current ones?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to run multiple query functions on the same sheet
But each query will return an undefined number of rows, I would like each new query table to appear under the previous one. But I can't leave an undefined number of rows to be filled... is there a way to get the query function to insert rows rather than fill current ones?

Comment: sort of.  there is a way to do what you want, but it's not really inserting rows.  please share a link to a sample sheet with some sample data and a manual recreation of the desired outcome.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aNgwy_ZPoT_ri0Cbqpo9MD4gnuAvYI9LMpNFQGRt-VU/edit?usp=sharing     Here is a link to a sample, you can see that for data 2 it wont insert as there aren't enough rows, but the data I will be using will be constantly updated,which means I cannot pre-determine how many rows will be needed

Comment: if you make the sheet editable (rather than comment only) I can demo the technique.  it should work fine for the way you have your data set up.

Comment: thank you, I think I have made it editable now